# How to Reset AlliedTelesis GS950 Websmart hardware

Tags: switch, ip-address, management

The switch described above had a management IP address configured. Unfortunately, the IP address of the switch was lost and the management cannot be accessed anymore. Is there a hardware reset on this switch so we can set it back to it's default IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to Reset Your device Press `Eco friendly Button`  5-9 seconds. It will take 01-2 min to reboot and It will remove all changes which you have done in last configurations.

If you want to reset to factory Default setting, Press `eco friendly button`  More than 10 second.

More details is [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/806116/Allied-Telesis-At-Gs950-48ps.html?page=34)